# Calculating cache memory based on LRU algorithm

Tags: paging, lru

Assuming i have 4 blocks of cache memory, Using the LRU (Least Recently Used) 
replacement algorithm on this following sequence of access to memory blocks: 1 2 3 4 5 2 5 4 1 5 2 3 :

```
1   2   3   4   5   2   5   4   1   5   2   3

1   1   1   1   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5
    2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2
        3   3   3   3   3   3   1   1   1   1
            4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   3
```

So in the end, the cache memory will contains this memory blocks : "5 2 1 3"

But the correct result is "1 5 2 3"

Please tell me what am I doing wrong here!

**Edit:**

I will be honest, I'm doing an excercise and can't get help from anywhere but here, and may be I misread the question, so this is the original question :

[image]

Comment: [Crossposted from cs.SE](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/30732/calculating-cache-memory-based-on-lru-algorithm).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So is my simulation of the LRU wrong? Honestly i still don't get it!

The simulation goes awry in column 5 where you add the newest data to the oldest position.

Here's the correction:

```
            1   2   3   3   3   2   2   4   1  <-- Oldest accesses
        1   2   3   4   4   2   5   4   1   5
    1   2   3   4   5   2   5   4   1   5   2
1   2   3   4   5   2   5   4   1   5   2   3  <-- Newest accesses
```

- Notice that the newest row is always equal to your input sequence.
- The other elements age one row at a time unless they are brought to the front with a new access

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I learned about LRU at this link : http://cs.uttyler.edu/Faculty/Rainwater/COSC3355/Animations/lrupagereplacement.htm , and it's approach is different with yours, may I ask why ?

Comment: I've shown the blocks in recency order (oldest at the top, newest at the bottom).  The animation doesn't show recency; instead, it shows *where* the data would be stored (in the block vacated by the least recently used data).   The question given you **Q25** appears to be asking for the ordered (newest to oldest) rather than *where* the blocks would be stored.

Comment: AH, now I get it, thanks so much, this has been torturing me for days!

Answer (score 4):

In a straightforward cache, the order doesn't matter. And the LRU algorithm is simple enough that you don't need to run the whole simulation. Just look at the last 4 numbers in your sequence:

```
... 1 5 2 3
```

Comment: You just work backwards. The last number was 3, so that must be present in the LRU. The number before was 2, which isn't equal to 3, so it too must be present.

Comment: So is my simulation of the LRU wrong? Honestly i still don't get it!

Comment: It's right. Order doesn't matter. 5213 contains the same numbers as 1523. But it's also more work.

Comment: Oh, sorry I didn't make it clear, order does matter! There were choices : `a)  1 2 3 5  b)  1 5 2 3  c)  3 2 5 1  d)  5 2 1 3`

Comment: Well, in that case your answer is right. It's trivial to prove as a MC question, even: the first 5 must replace the 1 in first place LRU), and that 5 can only be displaced if it's followed by a sequence of numbers containing 1-4 but not 5.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not a MC question :(. I've been struggle with the question `Why` for 2 days, I was only given answers, not explanations, so I have no choices but to ask here! :(

Comment: How is it NOT a Multiple Choice question when there are 4 choices A-D listed?! And your answer is correct.

Comment: Yes, and the right answer is B (1 5 2 3) not my calculation D (5 2 1 3)

Comment: And by using LRU algorithm, it should be D, but I know that's not the correct answer! Just don't know why

Comment: I edited the question with a snap shot of the original question, may be I'm missing something?

Answer (score 2):

According to Abraham Silberschatz *Operating System Concepts* 8th edition Chapter 9 figure 9.15. The order of cache in the CPU doesn't matter. What is important is the cache miss or page-fault rate.

However, in this question is asking the order of cache in the CPU not what is in the caches.  So, Raymond Hettinger's way will give you the correct answer for the question.

Unfortunately, good CPU design will not work this way.  Since, each cache block has to refresh with the new data with each input.  This defeat the purpose of using cache!